# Does solution of $ x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-A_n/x}$ exist?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Usually when working with indefinite sums, I want to work out the sum or whether it convergence. But now I encountered a problem they other way around and I'm clueless...

Is there even a general solution of $$ x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-A_n/x}$$
for $A_n$, where $x$ is given and real, $A_n >0\space\forall n$ and $\frac{dA_n}{dx}=0\space\forall n$?

Thank you

EDIT:

To make my question clearer for the commenters and others, I'm searching for a systematic sequence $A_n$ which, when entered in the equation above, yields $x$ and this should hold for all (real) $x$.

Comment: You want to solve for $A_n$?  That seems to be one equation in an infinite number of unknowns.  To have convergence, you need the $A_n$ to increase fast enough, but once you do, you can bump $A_1$ up and $A_2$ down and maintain the equality.  I'm not sure to make of the condition $\frac{dA_n}{dx}=0\space\forall n$

Comment: Does not make much sense to me. You could, for example set $a_n = b (n+1)$

Comment: @Ross, the condition $\frac{dA_n}{dx}=0$ only means $A_n$ does not depend on $x$. I state this for completeness, otherwise a trivial solution could be found, e.g $A_n(x)=-x(log(x)+e^{π2/6n^2})$. @leonbloy: That $A_n$ is not a solution of the equation.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I misinterpreted the question to mean the equality held for all $ x $.

Comment: But what does `$A_n$ does not depend on $x$` mean? Given a certain solution sequence $A_n$, either it satisfies the equation for a fixed $x$ (and then it is implicitly a function of $x$ : different $x$ give different $A_n$), either it satisfies the equation for all $x$ (I'd like to see that)

Comment: The limit of the rhs is infinity as $x\to-0$.

Comment: Clearly the right-hand side is always positive, so this can only happen for $x>0$. @Ross, you answer shows that this can always be arranged so that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-A_m/x}$ converges to a function $x$ for at least one point; I think the interesting question that's hiding in here is whether it's possible for the series to converge to $x$ for $0<a<x<b$ for some interval $(a,b)$ in the positive reals.

Comment: Quantifier abuse police is here!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It cannot be done. For the proof write $x:={1\over y}$. Then we should have
$${1\over y}\ \equiv\ \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-A_n y}\qquad(*)\ ,$$
say for all $y\geq1$. In particular $\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-A_n}=1$, so necessarily $\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n=\infty$. It follows that $\alpha:=\inf_n A_n>0$ and therefore
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-A_n y}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-A_n} \ e^{-A_n(y-1)} \leq e^{-\alpha(y-1)} \qquad (y\geq1)\ .$$
This shows that $(*)$ cannot hold for all $y\geq 1$.

Comment: Brilliant. This in fact shows that if $\frac 1y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-A_ny}$ and $\frac1x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-A_nx}$ with some $y>x$, then $\frac xy\leq e^{-\alpha(y-x)}$, limiting the intervals on which we could have convergence (because when $x/y\to0$ slower than $e^{-\alpha(y-x)}$ as $y\to\infty)$. Some numerical exploration with Mathematica suggests that for $\alpha\geq 1$, $x\geq 1$ the above system has no solution other than $x=y$, which seems to follow by computing derivatives $-x/y^2>-1>-\alpha e^{-\alpha(y-x)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly there are many solutions.  As $x$ grows, the right side decreases monotonically, so for any series $A_n$ that is convergent there will be an $x$ that solves the equation.  So pick any $x$ and series $A_n$ that solve the problem.  Given a different $x$, just change your favorite $A_n$(s) to make it work.

For a specific example, take $x=1, A_n=\ln 2^{n+1}$.  If you want a solution for $x=2$, just decrease any set of $A_n$'s to add enough to the RHS.

Comment: Two remarks on your post. First, a necessary condition for the RHS to be finite is that $A_n\to+\infty$. Second, more importantly, the RHS is nondecreasing.

Comment: @Didier:  I remarked on the need for $A_n$ to increase in my comment on the original question.  I was more focused on the fact that there are so many solutions the problem is not too interesting.

Comment: But, of course, this implies that $A_n$ is implicitly a function of $x$

Comment: @Ross: My remarks addressed your post and your post only, and specifically your *As $x$ grows, the right side decreases monotonically* and *for any series $A_n$ that is convergent*. I can understand neither of them. First, as $x$ grows, the RHS increases. Second, for any sequence $(A_n)$ such that $A_n\not\to+\infty$ and any fixed positive $x$, $\mathrm{e}^{-A_n/x}\not\to0$ when $n\to+\infty$, hence the RHS is infinite.

Comment: @Ross: Not interested in clarifying the above?

Comment: @Didier:  I thought the problem was to find a set of $A_n$ given a particular $x$, not to find a set of $A_n$ that works for all $x$.  This was because "$x$ is given and real".  It feels to me like a solution over an interval as Vladimir Sotirov suggests will not work because it is trying to fit uncountably many points with only countably many $A_n$.  But that is not a proof.

Comment: @Ross: Sorry but this does not address either one of the two specific points I made.

Comment: @Didier:  Oops, you are right about the RHS increasing with increasing $x$.  As $x$ grows, the exponent becomes less negative, so the RHS does increase.  I did not mean to assert that the series converges for all choices of $A_n$, just that you needed a set of $A_n$ that would make the sum converge.  As you say, they must increase to infinity, but I did not think about how fast they must.

Answer (score 1):

Divide both sides by $x$ to get:
$$1 = \Sigma\frac{e^{-A_n/x}}{x},$$
As $x\to \infty$, the left hand side is 1 while the right hand side goes to zero for each $n$.

This might give a hint on what $A_n$ won't work.

Comment: It seems that what's going on here is that we're trying to write $1/x$ as a Fourier transform but where the transform is restricted to involve only a countable number of frequencies $A_n$. That's clearly impossible.

Comment: you're right that what's happening is writing $-1/x$ as a series in $\{e^{mx}\}$ for positive real $m$. I agree that this is impossible *when we require the series to converge absolutely*, but I'm not sure that we have impossibility under conditional convergence (to a non-holomorphic function).